# XSLT HTML table to LaTeX (rowspan)

Tags: xslt, latex, html-table

I am transforming HTML table to LaTeX using XSLT. It works but I need also support for `rowspan` attribute. Support for both attributes (colspan, rowspan) on one element would be nice. I am using XSLT 2.0. Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks.

HTML I want to transform looks like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>ipsum</td>
        <td>dolor</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sit</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">amet</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>adipisicing</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sed</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>ipsum</td>
        <td>dolor</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="table">
        <xsl:text>\begin{center}\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {</xsl:text>

        <xsl:for-each select="tr[1]/*">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:text>X[l,m]</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>X[c,m]</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:text>}
            \toprule
        </xsl:text>

        <xsl:apply-templates />

        <xsl:text>
            \bottomrule
            \end{tabu}  
            \end{center} 
        </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tr">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <xsl:text> \\&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@colspan">
                    <xsl:text>\multicolumn{</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@colspan"/>
                    <xsl:text>}{l}{</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>    
            <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::td)">
                 <xsl:text> &amp; </xsl:text> 
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Expected output in LaTeX is

```
\begin{center}\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[l,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]}
    \toprule
       Lorem &   ipsum &   dolor &   Lorem   \\
       sit &  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\multirow{3}{*}{amet}} &  Lorem   \\
       adipisicing & \multicolumn{2}{l}{} &  Lorem   \\
       sed & \multicolumn{2}{l}{} &  Lorem   \\
       Lorem &  ipsum &   dolor &   Lorem   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabu}  
\end{center}
```

Comment: Could you possibly to edit your samples to show what the expected output would be like if there was a `colspan` and `rowspan` on one element? Thank you!

Comment: @TimC: Yes, I edited my question. If there is a `colspan` and `rowspan` on one element, there must be blank `\multicolumn{}{}{} &` in the following rows instead of only `&` (used in case of only rowspan).